# Babel not transpiling from JSX to JS, tried manually without using webpack/browserify/bower

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs

I am trying basic example in React.JS and using Babel to transpile from jsx to js. I hope I installed all babel dependencies, shown in package.json below. Also added App.jsx and index.html pages.

As shown in line 8 of package.json, I am trying to execute babel with "npm run build" but it is throwing error as shown in this terminal screenshot.

Any help appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens when you don't configure Babel (properly).

Add this to your `package.json`:

```
"babel" : {
  "presets": ["es2015", "react" ]
}
```

More information [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/).

Comment: Thank you, it's working. Is it mandatory to add this to package.json while using babel ?

Comment: I'm afraid it is, either to `package.json` or to `.babelrc`.

Comment: I have added it to .babelrc before but not sure where to place '.babelrc' file .

Comment: I believe in the current working directory (the directory where you run `npm run build` from).

Comment: awesome, Thank you so much once again :)

Comment: @ihodonald perhaps create a new question with the specific issues that you're running in to, there's a lot that can go wrong when using Webpack so it may not be the same problem that the OP was trying to solve.

Comment: @robertklep thank you! I figured it out though. I didn't have the `babel-preset-es2015` package installed. :\